Can Ignite support this level of concurrency?
We are an online game project and we are considering using Ignite (version:2.14 java17) as a storage cache, with MongoDB (with write-behind enabled) as the backend database.
Assuming our concurrent storage volume is 9000/s, and the single storage volume is 30M.
I have the following questions:

Can Ignite support this level of concurrency? If so, how many nodes would I likely need, and how should I configure the JVM for each node?

Should I use asynchronous operations when interacting with MongoDB (CatchStore)?

By default, how many threads does Ignite use to store my data? Should I consider modifying this number?



Lots of questions here: You state that you need to write 9000 / second. Well 9000 10 byte records is much different than 9000 1 MB records! You total write throughput will dictate how many hosts you'll need to handle your aggregate data. Remember every time you add a additional Ignite host, you add more CPU, more network interfaces, and more memory! That is how Ignite scales!
Should you use async to write to your backing DB? This depends on the reliability that you need / require in the event of a host or network failure. If you were using write-through, then any host failure / network failure would result in an full operation failure with write-through. Async operations may not be persisted.
How many threads? You should not typically think of a distributed system as a threaded system. Yes they are threaded, but scalability is achieved by adding hosts. Why? Because data will be spread out to many hosts in a distributed system. If you have 10 hosts, then 1/10 of you data is on each host. Therefore each host is only handling 1/10 th of your total writes. If you need higher throughput then add more Ignite hosts!
Hope that helps.

thank you for your answer, it's very helpful. I would like to continue to ask: 1. Now suppose that the storage volume is 1M for each operation, and such storage operation is executed 9000 times in 1 second. How many nodes should I start? 10? 100? Or how do I know how many nodes I should start (assuming it's a Linux host with 8-core CPU and 16G memory)? 2. Do I need to set the number of threads for a single node? Or is it better to use the default value?
